# sort list using property variable

Tags: c#, sorting, reflection, compare

Suppose I have this list of process or any other object

```
List<Process> listProcess = new List<Process>();
```

I can sort it using this line `listProcess.OrderBy(p => p.Id);`
But what if I have only string name of property obtained in runtime. I assume, I should use reflection to get the property object. Can I use orderby method or I should use Sort and then pass own comparer?

Comment: You can also use OrderBy with name. What exactly is your question here?

Comment: Using Reflection maybe.. But the duplicate suggested by @DavidG solves your problem quite well.

Comment: @ArghyaC: Um, how can you use OrderBy with the name of a property, exactly? (Other than with reflection...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh o! My bad! I thought OP has `string` value of property "name"! Yes, reflection is the answer. `list.OrderBy(o => o.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(o))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a look at the post referred in the comment. Or, you can achieve that using simple reflection like this

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(o => o.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(o));
```

Where

```
List<object> list; //a list of any object(s)
string propName; //name of the property to be used in OrderBy
```